# Angular Doesn't Update ng-show

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-show

I have a table from which I have the representation of data that gets updated every 10 seconds or so, represented by the "current" list.  As you can see in the code snippet below, the two ng-show's depend on the Status value of an object.  I know that the list is getting updated with new values, so that the second ng-show should be showing and not the first, but it only updates when I refresh the page, not automatically. Shouldn't the ng-show's get updated automatically when the value of the Status field of the object gets changed?

```
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="object in current">
            <td>Name: {{object.Name}} <br /> Status: {{object.StatusMessage}}<br /> ID: {{object.ID}} <br /> User: {{object.UserName}}</td>
            <td>
                <div ng-show="object.Status == 2 || object.Status == 3">
                    <img ng-src="{{getScreenshot(object.Name)}}" style="width: 500px; height: 300px">
                </div>
                <div ng-show="object.Status < 2 || object.Status > 3" style="font-size: large; font-weight: bold">
                    Screenshot not available.
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: *How* is current being updated? Please provide the controller code.

Comment: Please provide controller code, i think , Angular is not updating your watchers.

Comment: Wrap your assigning into `$scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.current = newData; });`

Comment: Instead of `setTimeout` use the `$timeout` service. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) $apply has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is needed only when implementing custom event callbacks, or when working with third-party library callbacks.

Comment: @georgeawg, fact, that changes are not reflected on `ng-show` is consequence that code is executed out of inner $apply(i.e. as you wrote "via some custom stuff"), so it is needed to call it manually. What if it is not a plain `setTimeout`, that can be easily replaced by `$timeout`?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply AngularJS `$digest()` function.

For more information about `$digest()` function go to [AngularJS $watch() , $digest() and $apply()](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html)

You need to modify your controller code to something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.testValue = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    console.log($scope.testValue++);
    $scope.$apply() 
    }, 500);
});
```

Jsfiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/N2G7z/269/)